# Oracle - add counter to query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to add in a simple counter to an SQL Query - i.e., if I run a query on individual surnames that returns 3 results I would like the results to display their row value from the query. E.g.:

```
Surnames   Counter
Smith         1
Murphy        2
Brown         3
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Based on which sort criteria do you want that "counter"?

Answer (score 3):

The `row_number` analyitic function should do the trick:

```
SELECT surname, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY surname) AS counter
FROM   my_table
```

EDIT:
In a simple query like this, you could just use the rownum pseudocolumn:

```
SELECT   surname, rownum
FROM     my_table
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: Second query will return result in max to min, you have to use desc in order by clause to display as 1, 2, 3, so on...

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.*
, rownum rnum
from 
(select surname from name_table order by surname) a
```

will get you a simple numbering (according to the order of `surname`, but will not deal with ties.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
SELECT Surnames,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Surnames)
FROM t
```

**SQL Fiddle:-** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ad3aa/3

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Surnames,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Surnames) as Counter FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cerate an SQL Expression Field named something like 'RowNumber' with simply 'rownum' as the statement.  Add that field to where you want it in the details row, then sort your report by the name of your Expression Field, 'RowNumber' in this case.